# Grub loading Error 22, on trying to boot second hand Dell 1950 server

Tags: dell-poweredge

I bought a Dell PE 1950 on Ebay, the post runs through showing the SAS 5 controller and two hard drives, but then it hangs at Grub loading ... Error 22.

I want to put Windows web server 2008 on it, but it will not boot from CDROM (the disk is fine tried it on aother machine). It will boot to an Ubuntu 8 disk. ANy clues appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 8 cd or HDD? Also, are you sure you have a DVD and not a CD drive?

Comment: Doh! Its a CD drive and my windows server iso is on a dvd :-( Ubuntu is smaller so on a cd. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server comes with a CD-drive, not a DVD-drive. Since Windows 2008 is shipped on a DVD that won't work.

I doubt it will even run, so why don't you try to install Server 2003? Or if you really want 2008 you could PXE-boot it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error grub is trying to access a partition that does not exist.

the following excerpt was taken from [http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsserver2008r2general/thread/8c60fb5c-65eb-4028-a2e6-77ecd55c3b28)

As for installing windows 2008, you can make a bootable USB key to install 
diskpart {This will start diskpart from a command prompt}
list disk {This will list all available disks in the system}
select disk 1 {This will select your usb disk, if it is called 1 in your system}
clean {This will erase ALL information on the currently selected disk}
create partition primary
select partition 1
active
format fs=fat32
assign
exit

Then copy the files to the usb
xcopy d:*.* /s/e/f e:\

The second method is to open the case of the machine and install a DVD drive (temporarily) and install the OS normally